# iOS swift Alamofire parsing, creating generic class to parse json data

Tags: ios, json, swift, generics, alamofire

I have this JSON data to parse :

```
{
    "data": {
        "user_name": "JohP llDoe",
        "email_address": "tozto@gmail.com"
    },
    "result": {
        "code": 0
    }
}
```

The data type change from a web-service to another, but the general structure is always the same.

So I create this general Class using EVReflection to parse the Data :

```
class MyResponse<T>: EVObject {

    var data : T?
    var result : Result?

}

class Result: EVObject {
    var message : String = ""
    var code : Int = 0
}
```

and for the Data :

```
class Preaccount : EVObject {
    public var user_name : String = ""
    public var email_address : String = ""
}
```

And to call the web-service I created this method :

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)

            .responseObject { (response: DataResponse<MyResponse<Preaccount>>) in

                if response.result.isSuccess {

                    print(response.result.value!)
                }

                if response.result.isFailure {
                    let error : Error = response.result.error!
                }
        }
```

And now I'am having a bad access :

[image]

Is there a way to create a generic method and pass the parsed model in parameters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `Decodable` instead:

```
struct MyResponse<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let data: T?
    let result: Result?
}

struct Result: Decodable {
    var message: String?
    var code: Int
}

struct Preaccount: Decodable {
    let user_name: String
    let email_address: String
}

let data = """
{
    "data": {
        "user_name": "JohP llDoe",
        "email_address": "tozto@gmail.com"
    },
    "result": {
        "code": 0
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(MyResponse<Preaccount>.self, from: data)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
class MyResponse: EVObject {

    var data : Preaccount?
    var result : Result?

}
```

and to process response data

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)

            .responseObject { (response: DataResponse) in

     if response.result.isSuccess {

              print(response.result.value!)
             var myResponse = MyResponse(json:response.result.value!)
       }
   .......
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps me!

Answer (score 0):

Finally  here is my solution for the problem :

```
struct MyResponse<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    var data : T?
    var result : Result?
}

struct Result: Decodable {
    let message : String?
    let code : Int
    let form_errors : [String: [String]]?
}

struct Preaccount : Decodable {
    let user_name : String
    let email_address : String
}
```

And to call the web service :

```
func postRequest<T: Decodable>(url: String,
                                   params : [String: Any]?,
                                   returnType : T.Type)
    {

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)

            .responseDecodableObject { (response: DataResponse<FindoorResponse<T>>) in
                //...
        }
    }
```

And here is an example to call the method :

```
 AlamofireHelper.shared().postRequest(url: CHECK_USERNAME_URL, params: parameters, returnType: Preaccount.self)
```